# Bluetooth does not work - "can't load firmware" - Vaio - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, firmware

Everything goes well with my new Vaio laptop except the bluetooth. It is recognized in some way but it does not work.

I have already looked in askubuntu for similar cases but I don't find a solution anyway.

I did this:

```
~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[ 12.662286] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[ 12.662306] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 12.662314] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 12.662317] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 12.662323] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 12.701731] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 12.701735] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 12.701742] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 12.859623] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 12.859635] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 12.859640] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 81.946726] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly
[ 84.923846] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly

~$ rfkill list
0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

So I tried to install linux-firmware as suggested in a question here but it says I have the last version yet.

Also I found a suggestion about restarting gnome-bluetooth but it didn't work.

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have made some reasearch about a year ago and at that time they told me to change the wifi hardware card. this is what i found today: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1263351
(having the same problem here)